# Code Coverage - OldMap - NewMap

Tags: unit-test, map, update

I am having trouble with Code coverage of one If block - where I do have several conditions - and as per my point of view all are satisfied except **OldLeadMap** parameter.

Note:::::  I cant check my debug logs.

**CLASS Code**

```
public static void manageReassignmentDates(List<Lead> newLeads, Map<Id, Lead> oldLeadMap) {
    List<Id> leadsForAssignmentUpdate = new List<Id>();
    for (Lead objLead : newLeads) {
    if (objLead.Assignment_Status__c != oldLeadMap.get(objLead.Id).Assignment_Status__c){
            /* 
            *
            ************* Code  Need coverage ***** 
            **/
          }
  }
```

**Test Class Code**

```
    Lead l2 = new Lead();
    l2.LastName = 'testLead2';
    l2.Company ='testLead2';
    l2.Assignment_Status__c = 'Assigned';
    l2.OwnerId = usr.Id; //User is inserted
    l2.status = 'SomeStatus';
    insert l2;

    Map<Id, Lead> LdmapCode =  new Map<Id, Lead>();
    ldmapCode.put(l2.id,l2);

    l2.Assignment_Status__c = 'Reassigned';
    update l2;

    List<Lead> ldList = new List<Lead>();
    ldList.add(l2);

    LeadReassignmentManager.manageReassignmentDates(ldList,ldmapCode);
```

- Any Help or Suggestion ?!!!?
- Focus on "OldLeadMap" and "newLeads" parameter --> n tell me if my code is driving me with Records **having same values of fields in both Parameters** or they have different values for sure?

Comment: In your class what is objLead in your if statement? I don't see anything in your test code setting that value that you are using in your class.

Seems as if you are iterating over a list but not using anything in that list to get inside of your if statement.

Comment: Sorry about that .... Updated Question

Comment: Ok, a bit better. Now your if statement is checking for non-equality but you are comparing the Assignment_Status__c field from the same record. Therefore they will always be equal. Even though you are changing the field value after you put it in the map, you are changing the same record. So the record in the map and the list are the same.

Comment: @JesseMilburn - Yes , that was the primary doubt, Thank you.  NOW - Whats the solution for that :)

Comment: Well it depends on your use of this. I'm assuming this is within a trigger? If that is the case use the Trigger.new list and compare the values to the Trigger.old list. or Trigger.newMap compared to Trigger.oldMap. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm

Answer (score 3):

There are two observations:

**First one:**

You are adding same lead l2 in list as well as map. So Assignment_Status__c  will be having same value as "Assigned" and in your code you expect them to be different because of which your execution flow is not passing through if clause.

**Second one**
This code looks like is of trigger handler then why are you calling these methods explicitly. You could just fire update trigger to test the same, unless this is not trigger handler code.

Answer (score 3):

AS Kiran suggested just use the trigger functionality as that is what you seem to be calling this class with.

The comments are also correct that your list and map at the end of your test class have the same values...

**To stick with your current Framework**

```
Lead l2 = new Lead();

    l2.LastName = 'testLead2';
    l2.Company ='testLead2';
    l2.Assignment_Status__c = 'Assigned';
    l2.OwnerId = usr.Id; //User is inserted
    l2.status = 'SomeStatus';
    insert l2;

    List<Lead> ldList = new List<Lead>();    
    //note I an preserving the ID here so keep that in mind for downriver code
    ldList.add(l2.clone(true,true)); //Deep clone the l2 keeping the ID

    //Change the status of the original L2
    l2.Assignment_Status__c = 'Reassigned';


    Map<Id, Lead> LdmapCode =  new Map<Id, Lead>();
    ldmapCode.put(l2.id,l2);



    LeadReassignmentManager.manageReassignmentDates(ldList,ldmapCode);
```

**To do it via trigger**

```
trigger MyTrigger on Lead(before update){
    LeadReassignmentManager.manageReassignmentDates(trigger.new,trigger.oldMap);
}

Lead l2 = new Lead();

    l2.LastName = 'testLead2';
    l2.Company ='testLead2';
    l2.Assignment_Status__c = 'Assigned';
    l2.OwnerId = usr.Id; //User is inserted
    l2.status = 'SomeStatus';
    insert l2;

    //Change the status of the original L2
    l2.Assignment_Status__c = 'Reassigned';

    update l2;
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, I tried both-didn't worked. "ManageReassignmentDates(....)" is not called from TriggerHandler or from anywhere (and Sadly I cant change the class for now) ..... So to work around I need to cover this temporary (.... and wait for next release to remove this method from class) .

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend learning the [Selector](https://github.com/bluewolf-beyond/selector) library.

**Service**

```
public with sharing class LeadServices
{
    public static Select.Filter hasAssignmentStatusChanged()
    {
        return Select.Field.hasChanged(Lead.Assignment_Status__c);
    }
    public static void performAction(List<Lead> filterResults)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
@IsTest
class LeadServicesTest
{
    static final Integer RECORD_COUNT = Limits.getLimitQueries() + 1;

    static testMethod void testHasAssignmentStatusChanged_Changed()
    {
        // create RECORD_COUNT leads
        // clone oldMap
        // change oldMap Assignment_Status__c values

        Test.startTest();
            List<Lead> results = LeadServices.hasAssignmentStatusChange()
                .filter(newLeads, oldMap);
        Test.stopTest();

        system.assertEquals(RECORD_COUNT, results.size(),
            'Records where the Assignment Status changed should be returned');
    }

    static testMethod void testHasAssignmentStatusChanged_NotChanged()
    {
        // create RECORD_COUNT leads
        // clone oldMap
        // no need to change oldMap Assignment_Status__c values

        Test.startTest();
            List<Lead> results = LeadServices.hasAssignmentStatusChange()
                .filter(newLeads, oldMap);
        Test.stopTest();

        system.assert(results.isEmpty(),
            'Records where the Assignment Status did not change should be ignored');
    }
}
```

Now when you test `performAction`, you can pass it any `List<Lead>` you please, and it does not have to get through any additional filters.